# overlap image to another image - iphone

Tags: iphone, image, filter

I at all, I have a question, there is a way for overlap an image to another image?overllapping 2 image and save it?
After take it from my album, how can apply this filter?

Comment: Overlapping like one on top of the other, meaning the one behind "hidden"?

Comment: yes, like http://img.skitch.com/20090616-kcgr6p8q2jwxs42t97jtpsu9an.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, then you should easily achieve what you want like this:

```
imageViewOnTop .backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; //This sets your backgroung to transparent. 
imageViewOnTop.opaque = NO;
[imageViewBehind addSubview:imageViewOnTop];
[imageViewOnTop release];
```

`imageViewOnTop` being your "Hat", and `imageViewBehind` being your "Head". 
NOTE: your images should have an ALPHA capable image format like PNG, so only the Hat is visible and covering your Head, not the whole imageView Rectangle .
Hope its clear enough!

---

Oh you wanted to save your compiled image to the roll, then you should do this:

Comment: mmmm I solved in another way....- (UIImage*) addImageToImage:(UIImage*)img:(UIImage*)img2{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);
    
    // Draw image1
    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height)];
    
    // Draw image2
    [img2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, img2.size.width, img2.size.height)];
    
    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   
    return resultingImage;
}